# How to Render a LinkedList in ReactJS Component

Tags: reactjs, oop, linked-list, components, render

```
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
      this.value = value;
      this.next = null;
    }
  }
  
  class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
      this.head = null;
      this.tail = null;
      this.length = 0;
    }
  
    addToTail(value) {
      let newNode = new Node(value);
  
      if (!this.head) {
        this.head = newNode;
        this.tail = newNode;
      } else {
        this.tail.next = newNode;
        this.tail = newNode;
      }
  
      this.length++;
      return this;
    }
  
    removeFromTail() {
      if (!this.head) return null;
  
      let current = this.head;
      let newTail = current;
  
      while (current.next) {
        newTail = current;
        current = current.next;
      }
  
      this.tail = newTail;
      this.tail.next = null;
      this.length--;
  
      if (this.length === 0) {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
      }
  
      return current;
    }
  
    addToHead(value) {
      let newNode = new Node(value);
      if (!this.head) {
        this.head = newNode;
        this.tail = newNode;
      } else {
        newNode.next = this.head;
        this.head = newNode;
      }
      this.length++;
      return this;
    }
  
    removeFromHead() {
      if (!this.head) return null;
      let currentHead = this.head;
      this.head = currentHead.next;
      this.length--;
      return currentHead;
    }
  }
```

How do I render items in a linkedlist in a reactjs component as if mapping out elements from an array but instead inside this linkedlist class.

I am having difficulties implementing different classes like in Java where you have to extend the classes from different files, what is the equivalent of doing so but in ReactJS and using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list to an array

```
function getItems() {
  let current = list.head
  const array = []
  while (current) {
    array.push(current)
    current = current.next
  }
}
```

And then render it as usual

```
<>{ getItems().map(item => <div>{item}</div>) }</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the intermediate conversion to array with values as follows:

```
const renderList = (node: IDatum, arr: JSX.Element[] = []): JSX.Element[] => {

   arr.push(<li key={node.key}>{node.message}</li>);
   return node.next ? renderList(node.next, arr) : arr;

}

return <ul>{renderList(head)}</ul>;
```

But it is probably overkill.